# What is these "letter:" behind the code and what is used for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

```
f: function teste() {
  return 122
}


a: function teste2() {

}
b: console.log('teste')
```

I'm not sure why this works. I'm running this code in NodeJS 16+ and I want to know what is the letter before any code. And how do I use it effectively?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: It's something you should never ever use, except potentially for getting out of extremely nested loops and labels should only be used to label loops. Therefore, this example is non-sensical and should be avoided.

Comment: Your code will throw an error in strict mode because you can't label declarations, only statements.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Is this the complete code?

Comment: @Bergi For a moment I thought it could be a JS object missing the the wrapping `{}` but `b: console.log('teste')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are labels for statements.
In your example `b` is the label for the `console.log('teste')` statement.

Labels aren't often used, they are similar to using GOTO. But when they are used, they are used with `break` or `continue` so you can be explicit to where you're breaking or continuing the code run from.

As pointed out by @ruan-mendes, labels are invalid on statements in strict mode.

You can read more about them here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Not usually, always must be used with `break` or `continue`. Reminder that `f:` and `a:` are declarations, not statements so that is invalid in strict mode. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#labeled_function_declarations

Comment: "*labels are invalid in strict mode*" - that's not what Ruan said.